# sudoSlider issue - .setOption() is not working for some options

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the j[Query plugin called sudoSlider](http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/), and I am trying to set some options after the slider has been initialized.

If I initialize the sudoSlider like this:

```
var sudoSlider = $("#slider").sudoSlider({speed:500});
```

and then try to do

```
sudoSlider.setOption('prevNext', false);
```

the prev/next buttons do NOT disappear, like I would think they should.

I am also trying to do

```
sudoSlider.setOption('afterAniFunc', foo);
```

where foo has been defined as the needed function, but this does not work either.

How can I get this to work?  I do not have the ability to change the initialization call of the slider in question, so I need to change those options after the fact.

Answer (score 0):

I created SudoSlider, and the issue you are having is a bug.

You can fix it by giving the option argument in lowercase (so 'afteranifunc' instead of 'afterAniFunc').

You can also get a fixed JavaScript (version 2.2.2) on github: https://github.com/webbiesdk/SudoSlider, or the website: http://webbies.dk/SudoSlider/